# Re-write pure PHP code in Laravel 5.1 format

Tags: php, arrays, json, html, bootstrap-typeahead

I have this code running in pure PHP, I'll like to write it in Laravel 5.1 since I'm using Laravel for the development.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['query'])){
    
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
        mysql_select_db('tradersmart');
        $query = $_POST['query'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT name, timezone_id FROM geonames_names WHERE name LIKE '%{$query}%'");
        $arrayName = array();
        $arrayTimezone = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            $arrayName[] = $row['timezone_id'];
            $arrayTimezone[] = $row['name'];
        }
        echo json_encode($arrayName  +$arrayTimezone);
    }
?>
```

This is the HTML file: It uses JSON and typeahead to speed up suggestion.

```
<body>
        <div class="well">
            <input type="text" class="css-input" id="typeahead" data-provider="typeahead">
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#typeahead').typeahead({
                    source: function(query, process){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/source.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: 'query=' +query,
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            async: true,
                            success: function(data){
                                process(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Please read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests

Comment: Since you are already using Laravel for the development, it should be straightforward: create new controller to handle requests, create geonames_names model to fetch data from the DB, return JSON response. Which of these you are struggling with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679066/using-bootstrap-typeahead-in-laravel-5-1 @Alex Blex I have tried the implementation but not it's running. Please, I've posted the link of my implementation above. Though the json is returned but I think it's typeahead that's not working.

Comment: Readers are warned **not to use the PHP** in this question - it has a stonking great SQL Injection vulnerability in the middle of it. Really not safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you are asking for the Laravel way to do things there will be few steps to get this done. In short, you need to 1) create a model, 2) update your `routes.php` file, 3) create a controller, and (4) update your ajax call to reflect Laravel's routing conventions. I suggest using the command line `php artisan` commands  to create the Model and Controller as they will place the necessary files in the correct paths so that Laravel will autoload them for you.

1. Model - run `php artisan make:model GeoName` from the command line, this should create a model at `app/GeoName.php` in which you will need to change the tablename to reflect your custome name.

   ```
   <? namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class GeoName extends Model
   {

   // this will map your custom table name to laravel. 
   protected $table = "geonames_names"; 

   }
   ```

   Laravel will automatically expect the tablename to be a plural version of the model in this case it would look for `geonames`, to override that you'll need add the `protected $table` attribute above.
2. Update the `app/Http/routes.php` file to catch the AJAX post request.

   `Route::post('bootstrap/source','GeoNameController@ajaxQuery');`

   This will catch a `POST` request to `http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/cache`, there's more in the [Laravel Documents on routes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing) here.
3. Create a controller using `php artisan make:Controller GeoNameController --plain` in the command line. Plain was used here to stop the automatic scaffolding of the typical CRUD request types of index, create, edit, show, update and delete. This will create the file `app/Http/Controllers/GeoNameController.php`

   ```
   <?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;

   use App\Http\Requests;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

   class GeoNameControler extends Controller
   {
        // Add the following here

        public function ajaxQuery(Request $request){

            $query = $request->get('query');

            $geoNames = GeoName::where('name',$query)->lists('name','timezone_id')->get();

            return $geoNames;
        }
   }
   ```

   Keep in mind that `query` is used in `$query = $request->get('query');` because that is what you named the data variable in your ajax request. ( `data: 'query=' +query,`)
4. Finally, in your jQuery ajax request remove the `.php` in the request call. `url: 'http://localhost:2222/bootstrap/source'` as you'll never directly call files in Laravel, the routes files handles all the destinations for your application.

A few things of note, (1) Your database should be configured using the `.env` `and app/config.php` files, (2) Laravel will automatically detect that the jQuery ajax function is expecting a JSON response so Laravel will provide exactly what it asks for.

You will may likely run into an issue with XSFR token permission issue which you can read about how to resolve in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token) here. If you don't already know, the [Laravel's Master Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master) is excellent!

Of course there is a lot more to learn about using Laravel and many excellent Laravel resources out there. Good luck!