# Using Bootstrap Typeahead in Laravel-5.1

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-5.1, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to do the implementation of this pure PHP project ([Re-write pure PHP code in Laravel-5.1 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675286/re-write-pure-php-code-in-laravel-5-1-format)) in Laravel-5.1 version, and I'm yet to get what needs to be done right. Bootstrap Typeahead is not effected. I would appreciate being pointed to what I'm to do right.

This is the blade form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'created-products', 'method' => 'post'), array('id'=>'createproduct')) !!}
    {!! Form::token() !!}

        <link href="{!! asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') !!}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

    <p>{!! Form::select('countries', array('-1' => 'Select a Country') + $listedCountries) !!} </p>
    <p>{!! Form::text('typeahead', null, array('class'=>'well', 'placeholder'=>'enter your state'), array('id'=>'selectedCompanyHiddenId', 'data-provider'=>'typeahead')) !!}</p>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{!! asset('bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js') !!}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script>
            $(function(){
                    $('#typeahead').typeahead({
                        source: function(query, process){
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'UserAddressController.php?SelectLocationPlaces',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: 'query=' +query,
                                dataType: 'JSON',
                                async: true,
                                success: function(data){
                                    process(data);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
        </script>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the controller:

```
public function create()
    {
        $listedCountries = $this->showListedCountries();
        return view('useraddress.create')
        ->with('listedCountries', $listedCountries)
        ->with('returnedLocationPlaces', $this->SelectLocationPlaces());
    }
```

The method returning the records:

```
public function SelectLocationPlaces()
{
    if(isset($_POST['query']))
    {
        $query = $_POST['query'];
        $locationPlaces = LocationPlaces::where('name', 'like', "%{$query}%")->toArray();
        return json_encode($locationPlaces);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you need to ask right question. Why you think it is not working? i.e. what you do, what you expect to have, and what you actually have.

Comment: Exactly what I've done is this code. What I expect is that when I focus the textbox with the id=typeahead and type in any character it should select the matching records based on what is inputted. Since typeahead uses fuzzy search, from the matching record displayed the user would just need to select to fill the textbox without actually typing in a new value. Thanks. Looking forward to your input.

Comment: Your AJAX URL is pointing directly to your controller file, I don't think that's correct. Do you have a route for that? Take a look at the JS console errors.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough, but I asked what you do as a user, not as a developer. There are too many problems to resolve them at once. I would recommend to fix backend first, then fix frontend:  send a POST request to your controller from `curl`  - it is what you do as a client; observe output - it is what you actually get;  compare it with what  must be returned to frontend - it is what you expect. Add these 3 pieces of information to the question and get a straight answer.